# biblatex: in the bibliography cite translation in the form "translated by ... as ..."

Tags: biblatex

I would like to cite in the bibliography the translation into English of works in a foreign language, and I would like to do so in the form recommended by the Chicago Manual of Style, that is, in the form "Translated by Jean Translator as *Title of translation* (City: Publisher, Year)." From what I understand, the fields `related={<key>}` and `relatedtype={translatedas}` are the fields to use for that information in the database. But I cannot find a style that implements these fields in the way suggested by the Chicago Manual of Style. Biblatex-chicago ignores these fields completely. Biblatex simply prints the information about the translation after the information about the original, which I find potentially confusing to the reader. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{Badiou2006,
author = {Badiou, Alain},
title = {Logiques des mondes},
subtitle = {L'\^{e}tre et l'\'{e}v\'{e}nement 2},
location = {Paris},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions du Seuil},
date = {2006},
related={Badiou2009},
relatedtype={translatedas},
}
@book{Badiou2009,
author = {Badiou, Alain},
translator = {Toscano, Alberto},
title = {Logics of worlds},
subtitle = {Being and event 2},
location = {London},
publisher = {Continuum},
year = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

Citing a book by \textcite{Badiou2006}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This produces the following entry in the bibliography:

> Badiou, Alain (2006). *Logiques des mondes. L’être et l’événement 2*.
>   Paris: Éditions du Seuil. *Logics of worlds. Being and event 2*.
>   Trans. by Alberto Toscano. London: Continuum, 2009.

What I would like to have is the following:

> Badiou, Alain (2006). *Logiques des mondes. L’être et l’événement 2*.
>   Paris: Éditions du Seuil. Translated by Alberto Toscano as *Logics of
>   worlds. Being and event 2* (London: Continuum, 2009).

I assume that, with the requisite background knowledge, it would not be too difficult to write or modify a macro to accomplish this, but unfortunately I do not know the first thing about writing macros for LaTeX/Biblatex. If this is indeed not too difficult to do, could someone provide me with the code?

Many thanks in advance,
Wolfhart

Comment: Does changing `relatedtype={translatedas}` to `relatedtype={bytranslator}` do what you want? If not, what would need to be improved?

Comment: @moewe: Yes, it does! I would not have thought that it could be so simple. Thank you! There is just one small difference, namely that "Translated" is abbreviated to "Trans.", i.e., instead of "Translated by Alberto Toscano" I get "Trans. by Alberto Toscano". This is not really important, but I wonder: Could that be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `relatedtype={bytranslator}` instead of `relatedtype={translatedas}`.

In order to get "translated by Alberto Toscano" you can either use
`abbreviate=false` as load-time option like this

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
```

or

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{bytranslator = {translated by}}
```

though here you will lose the capabilities of `\lbx@sfromlang`/`\lbx@lfromlang` that are only available in `.lbx` files.

Comment: I realize now that there is a little problem with this solution. The solution works perfectly for books, but it does not work correctly for articles and incollections. This comment box does not provide enough space to give an example, so I don't know how I should proceed to give an example. Should I edit (i.e., add something to) the original question? Or ask a new question?

Comment: @Wolfhart Maybe it is better to ask a new question, as it seems that the standard `biblatex` `related:bytranslator` function is somewhat tailored to cater the need of  `@books`, `@collections`, but not `@article`, or the `@in...` types.

Comment: So I have asked a new question about this problem, to be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167058/biblatex-relatedtype-bytranslator-does-not-work-as-expected-with-article-and).