# biblatex: relatedtype={bytranslator} does not work as expected with @article and @incollection

Tags: biblatex

Yesterday I asked [how to include the translation of a work in the bibliography in the form "translated by ... as ..."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166711/biblatex-in-the-bibliography-cite-translation-in-the-form-translated-by-as). I was told to use the fields `related={<key>}` and `relatedtype={bytranslator}`. This worked very well for my purposes, at first. But then I realized that it works correctly only for `@book`, not for `@article` or `@incollection`. Take, for example, the following `@incollection` and its translation, which is an `@article`:

> Derrida, Jacques (2001). “Une certaine possibilité impossible de dire
>   l’événement”. In: *Dire l’événement, est-ce possible?* Paris:
>   L’Harmattan, pages 79–112.
>
> Derrida, Jacques (2007). “A certain impossible possibility of saying
>   the event”. Translated by Gila Walker. In: *Critical Inquiry* 33.2,
>   pages 441–461.

Combining the two with `relatedtype={bytranslator}` produces the following incomplete entry:

> Derrida, Jacques (2001). “Une certaine possibilité impossible de dire
>   l’événement”. In: *Dire l’événement, est-ce possible?* Paris:
>   L’Harmattan, pages 79–112. Translated by Gila Walker as “A certain
>   impossible possibility of saying the event” (2007).

The information about the journal and number in which the translation appeared is missing. That is, the entry should read (I think):

> Derrida, Jacques (2001). “Une certaine possibilité impossible de dire
>   l’événement”. In: *Dire l’événement, est-ce possible?* Paris:
>   L’Harmattan, pages 79–112. Translated by Gila Walker as “A certain
>   impossible possibility of saying the event”. In: *Critical Inquiry*
>   33.2 (2007), pages 441–461.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@incollection{Derrida2001,
author = {Derrida, Jacques},
title = {Une certaine possibilit\'{e} impossible de dire l'\'{e}v\'{e}nement},
location = {Paris},
publisher = {L'Harmattan},
year = {2001},
pages = {79-112},
booktitle = {Dire l'\'{e}v\'{e}nement, est-ce possible?},
related = {Derrida2007},
relatedtype = {bytranslator},
}
@article{Derrida2007,
author = {Derrida, Jacques},
translator = {Walker, Gila},
title = {A certain impossible possibility of saying the event},
journaltitle = {Critical Inquiry},
volume = {33},
number = {2},
year = {2007},
pages = {441-461},
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

Citing a text by \textcite{Derrida2001}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When I switch the `translator`, `related`, and `relatedtype` fields, (incorrectly) making the `@incollection` the translation of the `@article`, a similar truncation happens. Instead of

> Derrida, Jacques (2007). “A certain impossible possibility of saying
>   the event”. In: *Critical Inquiry* 33.2, pages 441–461. Translated by
>   Gila Walker as “Une certaine possibilité impossible de dire
>   l’événement”. In: *Dire l’événement, est-ce possible?* (Paris:
>   L’Harmattan, 2001).

I get

> Derrida, Jacques (2007). “A certain impossible possibility of saying
>   the event”. In: *Critical Inquiry* 33.2, pages 441–461. Translated by
>   Gila Walker as “Une certaine possibilité impossible de dire
>   l’événement” (Paris: L’Harmattan, 2001).

That is, the title of the book in which the `@incollection` appeared is missing.

Is this a bug? If so, is there a way around it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `related:bytranslator` macro works well only for `@book`s and similar entry types (I think). In order to make it work for `@in...` types, we need to modify the macro a bit.

For each of these entry types that need some more output we check for that type and print the desired information (the code for that is taken from `standard.bbx`).

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{related:bytranslator}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \renewbibmacro*{name:hook}[1]{%
      \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
        {\begingroup
         \mkrelatedstring%
         \lbx@initnamehook{#1}%
         \endgroup}
        {}}%
    \printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
    \clearname{translator}%
    \setunit*{\addspace\bibstring[\mkrelatedstring]{astitle}\space}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \ifentrytype{article}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{inbook}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \printfield{edition}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{incollection}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \printfield{edition}%
       \newunit
       \iffieldundef{maintitle}
         {\printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}}
         {}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{inproceedings}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \iffieldundef{maintitle}
         {\printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}}
         {}}
      {}
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printlist{location}%
      \iflistundef{publisher}
        {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
        {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
      \printlist{publisher}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printdate}
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{note}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{chapter}%
      \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
      \printfield{pages}}}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Derrida2001,
author = {Derrida, Jacques},
title = {Une certaine possibilit\'{e} impossible de dire l'\'{e}v\'{e}nement},
location = {Paris},
publisher = {L'Harmattan},
year = {2001},
pages = {79-112},
booktitle = {Dire l'\'{e}v\'{e}nement, est-ce possible?},
related = {Derrida2007},
relatedtype = {bytranslator},
}
@article{Derrida2007,
author = {Derrida, Jacques},
title = {A certain impossible possibility of saying the event},
journaltitle = {Critical Inquiry},
translator = {Walker, Gila},
volume = {33},
number = {2},
year = {2007},
pages = {441-461},
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{related:bytranslator}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \renewbibmacro*{name:hook}[1]{%
      \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
        {\begingroup
         \mkrelatedstring%
         \lbx@initnamehook{#1}%
         \endgroup}
        {}}%
    \printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
    \clearname{translator}%
    \setunit*{\addspace\bibstring[\mkrelatedstring]{astitle}\space}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \ifentrytype{article}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{inbook}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \printfield{edition}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{incollection}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \printfield{edition}%
       \newunit
       \iffieldundef{maintitle}
         {\printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}}
         {}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{inproceedings}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \iffieldundef{maintitle}
         {\printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}}
         {}}
      {}
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printlist{location}%
      \iflistundef{publisher}
        {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
        {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
      \printlist{publisher}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printdate}
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{note}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{chapter}%
      \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
      \printfield{pages}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Citing a text by \textcite{Derrida2001}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

This might not work for all cases, so there might be some modifications to be done for corner cases.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Your solution works well for the primary case I cited, but it does not work for the (hypothetical) reverse case where I make the incollection the translation of the article. With your code, this produces: Derrida, Jacques (2007). “A certain impossible possibility of saying the event”. In: Critical Inquiry 33.2, pages 441–461. Translated by Gila Walker as “Une certaine possibilité impossible de dire l’événement”. In: Dire l’événement,
est-ce possible? Translated by Gila Walker (Paris: L’Harmattan, 2001), pages 79–112. That is, "Translated by ..." appears twice.

Comment: @Wolfhart I have added a call to `\clearname{translator}` after the `translator` has been printed, that should prevent it from appearing twice. See the edited answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It occurs to me that the reason for the double "translated by ..." in the reverse case may be that the `translator` field is ambiguous in this case, i.e., it is not immediately clear whether it refers only to the article in the collection or to the whole collection.

Comment: @Wolfhart I thought that as well, and indeed I think the ´translator` field for `@inbook`s and the like refers to the whole book/collection, not the `@in...` work. Anyway, let me know what the edit gives you.

Comment: Yes, the edit takes care of the reverse case. Thanks a lot! As for the question of the ambiguity of `translator`, I looked at the manual. For the entry type `@article`, the manual specifies that "editor and related fields refer to the journal while translator and related fields refer to the article", but it makes no such (or contrary) specification for `@inbook` or `@incollection`. So I guess it is a bit ambiguous, although the analogy with `@article` suggests that `translator` refers only to the specific text, not the whole book or collection.

Comment: @Wolfhart Could you please amend your question above with the `.bib` entries for the problem you describe here?

Comment: @Wolfhart Glad it was a problem with an easy solution. And don't worry about the noise. Deleting this part of the conversation later on might be a good idea though, so as to not distract from the rest of the comments below the answer.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for that. Could we expect to have this feature (correctly handling "in..." translated entries in BibLaTeX by default?

Comment: @ppr Mhh, that would be something to ask the developers, I think. I wouldn't hold my breath though to see this in core `biblatex`. As you can see the implementation is considerably more messy then the standard one, maybe one could learn from `related:reprintfrom` to make things shorter ...