# Biblatex: in the bibliography, cite translation in the form “translated as …” when translator is unknown

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

A couple of years ago, [I asked how to make Biblatex cite, in the bibliography, the translation of a work in the form “translated by … as …”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166711/biblatex-in-the-bibliography-cite-translation-in-the-form-translated-by-as).

I was told, in that post, to use `relatedtype={bytranslator}` instead of `relatedtype={translatedas}`. This generally works well. However, I have just encountered a little problem, namely in cases where the translator is not specified. In such cases, I think, the words “by …” should be dropped, such that only “translated as [title of work]” remains. What happens, though, is that “translated by [title of work]” is produced. That is, rather than dropping the word “by” preceding the name of the translator, Biblatex drops the word “as” following the name. Can this be fixed?

Here is a MWE (note that this example is fictitious; the translator of that translation is in fact known; but I have encountered cases where the translator is not known):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{Badiou2006,
author = {Badiou, Alain},
title = {Logiques des mondes},
subtitle = {L'\^{e}tre et l'\'{e}v\'{e}nement 2},
location = {Paris},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions du Seuil},
date = {2006},
related={Badiou2009},
relatedtype={bytranslator},
}
@book{Badiou2009,
author = {Badiou, Alain},
title = {Logics of worlds},
subtitle = {Being and event 2},
location = {London},
publisher = {Continuum},
year = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

Citing a book by \textcite{Badiou2006}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This produces the following entry:

> Badiou, Alain (2006). *Logiques des mondes. L’être et l’événement 2*.
> Paris: Éditions du Seuil. Translated by *Logics of worlds. Being and
> event 2* (London: Continuum, 2009).

It should be "Translated as" instead of "Translated by". How can this be achieved?

**EDIT:**

The `relatedtype` should work not only with books, but also with articles in journals or collections such as the following:

```
@incollection{Althusser1976a,
author = {Althusser, Louis},
title = {Id\'{e}ologie et appareils id\'{e}ologiques d'\'{E}tat},
subtitle = {Notes pour une recherche},
location = {Paris},
publisher = {\'{E}ditions sociales},
year = {1976},
booktitle = {Positions, 1964--1975},
pages = {67-125},
related = {Althusser1971a},
relatedtype = {translatedbyas},
}
@incollection{Althusser1971a,
author = {Althusser, Louis},
translator = {Brewster, Ben},
title = {Ideology and ideological state apparatuses},
subtitle = {Notes towards an investigation},
location = {New York},
publisher = {Monthly Review Press},
year = {1971},
booktitle = {Lenin and philosophy and other essays},
pages = {127-186},
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `relatedtype={translationas}` suffice? In this case what is missing is the translator so the string to be printed before the translation is `translationas`, not `translationby`.

Comment: @Ivan: You are right, `relatedtype={translationas}` produces "Translated as". I did not know that this option existed. I only knew of `relatedtype={translatedas}`, which does not work for me, for the reasons explained in the linked post. Anyway, `relatedtype={translationas}` does not work for me either because, even though it produces what I want when the translator is missing, it does not produce what I want when the translator is present. In that case, it produces "Translated as [title]. Translated by [name]", whereas I would like "Translated by [name] as [title]". Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new `relatedtype` based on `bytranslator` that can deal with a missing translator.

The only trick here is to check if the `translator` is present and print different strings depending on whether or not it is present. For the remaining part `related:translatedbyas` below is a copy of [`related:bytranslator` from `biblatex.def` (ll. 2291-3008 in v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2991-L3008).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,abbreviate=false]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{translated}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  translated = {translated},
}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{related:translatedbyas}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \ifnameundef{translator}
      {\bibstring{translated}}
      {\bibstring{bytranslator}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \renewbibmacro*{name:hook}[1]{%
         \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
           {\mkrelatedstringtext{\lbx@initnamehook{##1}}}
           {}}%
       \printnames[bytranslator]{translator}}%
    \setunit{\addspace}
    \bibstring[\mkrelatedstringtext]{astitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printlist{location}%
      \iflistundef{publisher}
        {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
        {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
      \printlist{publisher}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printdate}}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Badiou2006,
  author      = {Badiou, Alain},
  title       = {Logiques des mondes},
  subtitle    = {L'être et l'événement 2},
  location    = {Paris},
  publisher   = {Éditions du Seuil},
  date        = {2006},
  related     = {Badiou2009},
  relatedtype = {translatedbyas},
}
@book{Badiou2009,
  author    = {Badiou, Alain},
  title     = {Logics of worlds},
  subtitle  = {Being and event 2},
  location  = {London},
  publisher = {Continuum},
  year      = {2009},
}
@book{Badiou2007,
  author      = {Badiou, Alain},
  title       = {Logiques des mondes},
  subtitle    = {L'être et l'événement 3},
  location    = {Paris},
  publisher   = {Éditions du Seuil},
  date        = {2007},
  related     = {Badiou2010},
  relatedtype = {translatedbyas},
}
@book{Badiou2010,
  author     = {Badiou, Alain},
  translator = {Toscano, Alberto},
  title      = {Logics of worlds},
  subtitle   = {Being and event 3},
  location   = {London},
  publisher  = {Continuum},
  year       = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Citing a book by \textcite{Badiou2006,Badiou2007}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Translated as Logics of worlds. Being and event 2 (London: Continuum, 2009).//Translated by Alberto Toscano as Logics of worlds. Being and event 3 (London: Continuum, 2010).]

---

Together with the code from [biblatex: relatedtype={bytranslator} does not work as expected with @article and @incollection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167058/35864) you'd probably end up with something like

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{related:translatedbyas}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \ifnameundef{translator}
      {\bibstring{translated}}
      {\bibstring{bytranslator}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \renewbibmacro*{name:hook}[1]{%
         \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
           {\mkrelatedstringtext{\lbx@initnamehook{##1}}}
           {}}%
       \printnames[bytranslator]{translator}%
       \clearname{translator}}%
    \setunit{\addspace}
    \bibstring[\mkrelatedstringtext]{astitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \ifentrytype{article}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{inbook}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \printfield{edition}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{incollection}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \printfield{edition}%
       \newunit
       \iffieldundef{maintitle}
         {\printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}}
         {}}
      {}
    \ifentrytype{inproceedings}
      {\usebibmacro{in:}%
       \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock
       \iffieldundef{maintitle}
         {\printfield{volume}%
          \printfield{part}}
         {}}
      {}
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printlist{location}%
      \iflistundef{publisher}
        {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
        {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
      \printlist{publisher}%
      \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
      \printdate}
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{note}%
      \newunit\newblock
      \printfield{chapter}%
      \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
      \printfield{pages}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you very much, moewe! Your solution works, it produces the desired result. However, at the same it throws an error on my system, namely `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \mkrelatedstringtext {\csuse {\abx@str @\blx@tempa }}`. Why is that, and can it be avoided?

Comment: @Wolfhart Update your TeX system. `\mkrelatedstringtext ` was added in version v3.16 of `biblatex` (released 2020-12-31). On an older system `\providecommand{\mkrelatedstringtext}[1]{{\mainlang #1}}` might work.

Comment: Adding `\providecommand{\mkrelatedstringtext}[1]{{\mainlang #1}}` solved the problem, thanks! There is one more issue left: I would like to combine the code you provided here with the code you provided in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167058 in order to make the new `relatedtype` work with entry types other than books. How can that be done? I thought that it might be as easy as putting the two pieces of code next to each other and replace `\newbibmacro*{related:bytranslator}[1]{%` in the previous code by `\newbibmacro*{related:translatedbyas}[1]{%` but that does not work.

Comment: @Wolfhart Putting the two definitions one after another into the document won't do it: The second definition will just overwrite the first. You have to actually combine the relevant code. See the edit, please.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! There are two more issues, I am afraid. 1) It is not clear to me whether the lines `\NewBibliographyString{translated}\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ translated = {translated},}` that are included in the original solution before `\makeatletter` must also be included in the revised solution. I tried both ways and could not see a difference.

Comment: 2) The revised solution behaves differently from the solution in post 167058 in the case of articles in collections. I added an example to the question above. In the case of this example, the solution in post 167058 produces `Althusser, Louis. 1976. “Idéologie et appareils idéologiques d’État. Notes pour une recherche.” In: Positions, 1964–1975. Paris: Éditions sociales, 67–125. Translated by Ben Brewster as “Ideology and ideological state apparatuses. Notes towards an investigation.” In: Lenin and philosophy and other essays (New York: Monthly Review Press, 1971), 127–186.`

Comment: [Continuation of preceding comment:] The revised solution in this post puts an extra `Translated by Ben Brewster` before `(New York..`. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @Wolfhart 1) Yes, the `\NewBibliographyString{translated}\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ translated = {translated},}` is required also for the new code. You can already see a difference in the MWE if you remove it. 2) I forgot to copy a line. Try again now, please.

Comment: Now it works perfectly, thank you very much!