# Citing an ancient arabic manuscript and its translation

Tags: biblatex, arabic

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
  @BOOK{Bag-26,
    author       = {{{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{محمد بن الحسن بن الكريم الكاتب البغدادي}} [al-Baghdadi, Muḥammad ibn al-Ḥasan Ibn al-Karīm]}},
    sortname     = {al-Baghdadi, M.},
    shortauthor  = {al-Baghdadi},
    editor       = {Perry, C.},
    translator   = {Perry, C.},
    title        = {{{{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{كتاب الطبيخ}}} Kitāb al-ṭabīkh  [The book of dishes]}},
    sorttitle    = {The book of dishes},
    indextitle   = {The book of dishes},
    langid       = {arabic},
    publisher    = {Prospect Books},
    location     = {London‎ (UK)},
    year         = {2005},
    isbn         = {9781903018422},
    library      = {Süleymaniye Library, Istanbul (Turkey), MS Ayasofya 3710},
    original     = {Aleppo (Syria) 1226},
  }
\end{filecontents} 

 %% ============================================================================
  % !Mode:: "TeX:UK:UTF-8"
  % !TEX program = XeLaTeX
  % !BIB program = biblatex
  % -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[notitlepage,british]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\usepackage{polyglossia}%foreign language support
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=UTF8,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}%bibliography
\usepackage{css-colors}% defines web-safe colours
\usepackage{doi}%give DOIs as hyperlinks in bibliography
\usepackage{fontspec}% font selecting commands
\usepackage{xcolor}%handle colours

\usepackage{hyperref}%hyperrefs in PDF, must be last package called, preloaded in beamer
\hypersetup{final=true,
            pdfauthor={Tester},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=Blue,%bibliography, dark blue
            linkcolor=Blue,%internal links, dark blue
            urlcolor=DodgerBlue,%internet, middle blue
            allbordercolors=White,
            pdftitle={Test}}

\setmainlanguage{en-GB}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{FreeSerif}

\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\maketitle

Test the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog\parencite{Bag-26}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

results in the following:[image]

There are 3 problems here:

- Although the Arabic author name is typeset as expected, the Arabic title is not. Why?
- Most people will happily use the modern, English translation of the work, but some may want to see the original manuscript. I have tentatively added its place and catalogue number in the “library” field. How can I output this in the bibliography?
- For those who want to trace the history of an idea, it would be useful to know the time and place of publication of the original document (tentatively placed in “original”)

I realise that for the latter two points, the “note” field could be used, but I use that routinely to describe why I may want to cite this work, e.g. “first description of x”, “counterargument to y” etc.

Comment: Please do not ask about several things at once. Each question on this site should be about one specific issue. That makes your question easier to answer and more helpful for other people. See for example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Comment: The Arabic in the title is not shown because the title is typeset in Italics and your font does not have Italic Arabic characters. Try something like `{\textnormal{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{كتاب الطبيخ الحسن}}` to force non-Italic typesetting or get a font with Italics for Arabic (not sure if that is a thing).

Comment: `biblatex` has some fields like `origdate`, `origlocation`, `origpublisher`, `origtitle`, but they are not shown by the standard styles, so you would have to modify your style and tell it how to print these fields. In general it's nicer to use the `related` feature to add information on translated or original works (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/581496/35864).

Comment: As with all the `orig...` fields, `library` is a field defined in the standard data model, but it is not shown by the standard styles.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everybody. This helped a lot. The solution would look like:

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
  @BOOK{Bag-26,
    author       = {{{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{محمد بن الحسن بن الكريم الكاتب البغدادي}} [al-Baghdadi, Muḥammad ibn al-Ḥasan Ibn al-Karīm]}},
    sortname     = {al-Baghdadi, M.},
    shortauthor  = {al-Baghdadi},
    title        = {{{{\textnormal{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{كتاب الطبيخ}}}} Kitāb al-ṭabīkh}},
    sorttitle    = {The book of dishes},
    indextitle   = {The book of dishes},
    langid       = {arabic},
    library      = {Süleymaniye Library, Istanbul (TR), MS Ayasofya 3710},
    location     = {Aleppo (SY)},
    year         = {1226},
    related      = {Bag-05},
    relatedtype  = {translatedbyas},
  }

@BOOK{Bag-05,
    author       = {{{\foreignlanguage{arabic}{محمد بن الحسن بن الكريم الكاتب البغدادي}} [al-Baghdadi, Muḥammad ibn al-Ḥasan Ibn al-Karīm]}},
    editor       = {Perry, C.},
    translator   = {Perry, C.},
    title        = {The book of dishes},
    publisher    = {Prospect Books},
    location     = {London‎ (UK)},
    year         = {2005},
    isbn         = {9781903018422},
}

@ARTICLE{Smi-39,
  AUTHOR       = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Смирнов, Н.}} [Smirnov, N.]}},
  sortname     = {Smirnov, N.},
  shortauthor  = {Smirnov},
  TITLE        = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Об уклонениях эмпирической кривой распределения}}} [On deviation of the empirical distribution curve]},
  sorttitle    = {On deviation of the empirical distribution curve},
  YEAR         = {1939},
  JOURNAL      = {{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Мат. Сборник}} [Math. Collect.]},
  volume       = {6(48)},
  number       = {1},
  pages        = {3-26},
  langid       = {russian},
  url          = {http://www.mathnet.ru/links/9c480a97757553ea3504fc444cde8430/sm5810.pdf},
}

@BOOK{Thu-11,
  AUTHOR       = {{{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Θουκυδίδης}} [Thoukydídēs]}},
  TITLE        = {{{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Ιστορία του Πελοποννησιακού Πολέμου}}}},
  address      = {Athens (GR)},
  year         = {411 BC},
  related      = {Thu-10},
  relatedtype  = {translatedbyas},
}

@BOOK{Thu-10,
  AUTHOR       = {{{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Θουκυδίδης}} [Thoukydídēs]}},
  title        = {History of the Peloponnesian War},
  translator   = {Crawley, R.},
  publisher    = {J. M. Dent \& E. P. Dutton},
  address      = {London (UK), Toronto (CA) \& New York (NY, USA)},
  year         = {1910},
  url          = {https://archive.org/details/pelocrawleyr00thucuoft/page/n7/mode/2up},
}

\end{filecontents}

 %% ============================================================================
  % !Mode:: "TeX:UK:UTF-8"
  % !TEX program = XeLaTeX
  % !BIB program = biblatex
  % -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[notitlepage,british]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\usepackage{polyglossia}%foreign language support
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=UTF8,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}%bibliography
\usepackage{css-colors}% defines web-safe colours
\usepackage{doi}%give DOIs as hyperlinks in bibliography
\usepackage{fontspec}% font selecting commands
\usepackage{xcolor}%handle colours

\usepackage{hyperref}%hyperrefs in PDF, must be last package called, preloaded in beamer
\hypersetup{final=true,
            pdfauthor={Tester},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=Blue,%bibliography, dark blue
            linkcolor=Blue,%internal links, dark blue
            urlcolor=DodgerBlue,%internet, middle blue
            allbordercolors=White,
            pdftitle={Test}}

\setmainlanguage{en-GB}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{FreeSerif}


\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\maketitle

Test the quick\parencite{Smi-39} brown fox jumps\parencite{Thu-11} over the lazy dog\parencite{Bag-26}.

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Biber complains about the "BC" in the year of the Thoukydídēs, but that doesn't affect the result. I still have to work on the library-field, probably best in a new document type "manuscript", which really isn't the same as "book".

The result is
[image]

Comment: For the BC thing: Use the `date` field and a negative sign to denote BC dates. (`date = {-0410},` in the `.bib` entry plus the option `dateera=christian,` for BC or `dateera=secular,` for BCE). (The apparent off-by-one error is due to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero.)

Comment: Since none of the bib-styles I use require sorting by year, it is probably easier and less error-prone to just live with the warning message. Sources that were published BC occur only very rarely in my work, anyway. In my current book project, exactly two out of 1190. But thanks very much.